# Informações não aparecem no formulário ao editar

Tags: python, django

Com a chave primaria ID, trabalho com as informações no views, porém não aparece no editar(html), os campos setor e empresa aparece.

Views

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def ed_ramal(request):
    id_ramal = request.GET.get('id')
    id_setor = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal).values('setor_ramais')
    id_empresa = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal).values('empresa_ramais')

    if id_ramal:
        ed_ramal = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal).values('ramal')
        i_resp = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal).values('nome_resp')
        i_mail = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal).values('email')
        setor = Setores.objects.filter(id=id_setor[0]['setor_ramais'])
        empresa= Empresas.objects.filter(id=id_empresa[0]['empresa_ramais'])
        dados = {'ramal': ed_ramal, 'responsavel': i_resp, 'email': i_mail, 'setores': setor, 'empresas': empresa}
    else:
        empresa = Empresas.objects.all()
        setor = Setores.objects.all()
        dados = {'empresas': empresa, 'setores': setor}
    return render(request, 'ramal.html', dados)
```

Html que é chamado para fazer a edição, estou passando o id(chave primaria do ramais )

```
<section class="container w-auto bgcolor_cad">
        <form action="submit" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
         <input type="number" name="id_ramal" value="{{ i.id }}" hidden>
           <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">

                  <label>Ramal:</label>
                  <input type="number" name="ramal" class="form-control" value="{{ i.ramal }}"  >
                </div>
                <div class=" col-md-4">
                  <label>Responsável:</label>
                  <input type="text" name="responsavel"  class="form-control" value="{{ i.nome_resp }}" >
                </div>
          </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email"  class="form-control" value="{{ i.email }}">
                  </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <label >Setor:</label>
                      <select id="inputState" name="setor" class="form-control">
                        {% for s in setores %}
                            <option  value="{{ s.id }}" name="pk_setor">{{ s.setor }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </select>
                        <a href="/ramais/edicao/setor/">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">ADICIONAR</button>
                        </a>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label for="inputState">Empresa:</label>
                      <select id="inputState01" name="empresa"  class="form-control">
                        {% for e in empresas %}
                            <option  value="{{ e.id }}" name="pk_empresa">{{ e.nome_emp }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </select>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SALVAR</button>
            <a href="/ramais/">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">CANCELAR</button>
            </a>
        </form>
```

Models

```
class Setores(models.Model):
    setor = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'setores'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.setor

class Empresas(models.Model):
    nome_emp = models.CharField(max_length=250,verbose_name='Empresa')
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=21, verbose_name='CNPJ')
    insc_estadual= models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True, verbose_name='Inscrição Estadual')
    telefone_emp = models.CharField(max_length=13, verbose_name='Telefone')
    rua = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Endereço')
    numero = models.CharField(max_length=6, verbose_name='Número')
    complemento = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, verbose_name='Complemento')
    bairro = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Bairro')
    cep = models.CharField(max_length=9, verbose_name='CEP')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'empresas'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_emp


class Ramais(models.Model):
    ramal = models.CharField(max_length=4, verbose_name='Ramal')
    nome_resp = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Responsavél')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60)
    setor_ramais = models.ForeignKey(Setores, on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Setor')
    empresa_ramais = models.ForeignKey(Empresas,on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name='Empresa')
    data_criacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ramais'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ramal + str(self.setor_ramais)+ str(self.empresa_ramais)

    def get_data_criacao(self):
        return self.data_criacao.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viva, o teu código tinha alguns problemas, não sei se estás a fazer o mesmo no restante html colocas a tag button dentro de anchor  não deves fazer isso, tens [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5) com mais detalhes e sugestões. Corrigi o teu código, mas só irá mostrar os dados que queres se na url passares **url?id={id_ramal}**. Voce continua não entendendo bem com funciona o envio de valores através do context de Django para o template. De onde surge o {{ i.email }} se defines na tua view e envias pelo context {...'email': i_mail...} no template seria {{ email }}, o 'i' surge de uma iteração de um for? Onde ele está? Server side, estavas a efetuar multiplas consultas para obter dados da db, duas delas desnecessárias. Bem sem perceber o que pretendes, a tua informação nas dúvidas não são muito claras, mas fica aqui a resolução dos problemas.

NOTA:
Na prática mudei a consulta de ramais = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal) para ramais = Ramais.objects.get(id=id_ramal), desta forma não retorna um queryset mas sim o objeto e acessível através do valor ramais passado pelo context, para aceder aos seus dados basta fazer **ramais.id**, por exemplo.
Na linha id_ramal = request.GET.get('id'), só irás conseguir obter o id se passares na rota, ou seja, como expliquei antes, **url?id={id_ramal}**.

Espero ter esclarecido porque não mostrava dados no teu template.

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def ed_ramal(request):
    template_name = 'ramal.html'
    context = {}
    id_ramal = request.GET.get('id')
    id_setor = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal).values('setor_ramais')
    id_empresa = Ramais.objects.filter(id=id_ramal).values('empresa_ramais')

    if id_ramal:
        ramais = Ramais.objects.get(id=id_ramal)
        setor = Setores.objects.filter(id=id_setor[0]['setor_ramais'])
        empresa= Empresas.objects.filter(id=id_empresa[0]['empresa_ramais'])
        context = { 'ramais': ramais, 'setores': setor, 'empresas': empresa}
    else:
        empresa = Empresas.objects.all()
        setor = Setores.objects.all()
        context = {'empresas': empresa, 'setores': setor}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

**ramal.html**

```
<form action="submit" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
         <input type="number" name="id_ramal" value="{{ ramais.id }}" hidden>
           <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">

                    <label>Ramal:</label>
                    <input type="number" name="ramal" class="form-control" value="{{ ramais.id }}"  >
                </div>
                <div class=" col-md-4">
                    <label>Responsável:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="responsavel"  class="form-control" value="{{ ramais.nome_resp }}" >
                </div>
          </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email"  class="form-control" value="{{ ramais.email }}">
                  </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label >Setor:</label>
                    <select id="inputState" name="setor" class="form-control">
                    {% for s in setores %}
                        <option  value="{{ s.id }}" name="pk_setor">{{ s.setor }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                    <a href="/ramais/edicao/setor/" class="btn btn-info">ADICIONAR</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label for="inputState">Empresa:</label>
                      <select id="inputState01" name="empresa"  class="form-control">
                        {% for e in empresas %}
                            <option  value="{{ e.id }}" name="pk_empresa">{{ e.nome_emp }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </select>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">SALVAR</button>
            <a href="/ramais/" class="btn btn-danger">CANCELAR</a>
        </form>
```

Comment: Obrigado, está funcionando. Não sei utilizar essas consulta no db, sei fazendo pelas ferramentas. E no caso do i.ramais no template, não sabia como enviar os dados e achei que seria "i.ramais" como um "for", porém entendi que você colocou "ramais.id" seria "ramais" do banco de dados, né?

Comment: Viva, ao passar pelo context o objeto 'ramais', este tem vários atributos e um deles o id, para aceder a este via template basta isso, ramais.id.

Comment: muito obrigado. Me ajudou muito e esse é o meu primeiro sistema. Não vou errar mas esses detalhes.